# Getting Session Properties (Username and Password) for QuickFix/n

Tags: c#, quickfix, fix-protocol, quickfixj

I have put my user name and password on the FIX configuration file. So I must think I should be able to get User name and passwords from some internal variable like session variable or SessionSetting variable or session.SessionDataDictionary or some other variable. However, I did not find any straight forward solution to get Username and Password from internal variable.

```
[SESSION]
BeginString=FIX.4.4
SenderCompID= xxxxx
Username= xxxx
Password= xxxx
```

Probably this is very doable, logically speaking. However, neither anyone suggest to do this or I have not seen anyone doing this on google. Only code bit I found from google is this.

```
String username = sessionSettings.getString(sessionId, "Username"); //only works for Java version of QuickFix
```

However above code is only working for Java Version of QuickFix and this method is not available in DotNet Version of QuickFix (i.e. QuickFix/n)

```
getString(sessionId, "Username");
```

I am looking to achieve similar results for FIX 4.4 using QuickFix/n. 
This might be very simple task if someone is familiar with QuickFix. 
I will really appreciate your tips or advice. I would not mind if you have some idea for Java or C++ version as they are all quite similar. I just need to know in which variable this user name and password is stored and how can I get this using Csharp code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you debug and see where the file variables are read and use the same methods ?

Comment: Hi. Very good point. However, QuickFix load configuration file from SessionSetting constructor. It does not have get methods within SessionSetting class. But rather, my guess is that it must have some dedicated class for get methods and to get user name and password from configuration file. Due to complex structure of QuickFix, I still did not find which class is the one I should access to the get method. Sorry for bad explanation. QuickFix is complicated and my head is complicated too. :) :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are on the right track with `String username = sessionSettings.getString(sessionId, "Username");`, but the method call in QuickFIX/n is slightly different.

The call is more like `sessionSettings.Get(sessionId).GetString("Username");`.

See this example:

```
var configuration =
    new System.Text.StringBuilder().AppendLine("[ DEFAULT ]")
        .AppendLine("ConnectionType=initiator")
        .AppendLine("[SESSION]")
        .AppendLine("BeginString=FIX.4.4")
        .AppendLine("SenderCompID=Sender")
        .AppendLine("TargetCompID=Target")
        .AppendLine("Username=Gandalf")
        .AppendLine("Password=YouShallNotPass")
        .ToString();
var settings = new SessionSettings(new System.IO.StringReader(configuration));
var session = new SessionID("FIX.4.4", "Sender", "Target");
var sender = settings.Get(session).GetString("SenderCompID"); // Returns Sender
var user = settings.Get(session).GetString("Username"); // Returns Gandalf
var pass = settings.Get(session).GetString("Password"); // Returns YouShallNotPass
```

For reference, see the [unit tests for SessionSettings](https://github.com/connamara/quickfixn/blob/master/UnitTests/SessionSettingsTest.cs#L182).

Comment: No doubt. This is the best answer. Thanks so much to share your valuable experience. :) :)